Showing $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm e}^{-t\left(1 - p/2\right)}}{\left(1 + t\right)^{p}}{\rm d}t$ is finite iff $p \leq 2 $
I want to prove
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm e}^{-t\left(1 - p/2\right)}}{\left(1 + t\right)^{p}}{\rm d}t
\quad\mbox{is finite} \quad\iff\quad p \leq 2
$$
However, I don't have any ideas to prove this.
Any recommendations? Please.

So you want to calculate or just to prove when it is finite?

I want to prove it

I think that is not true, for instance if $p=4$ then the integral is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^t}{(1+t)^4} dt$. As the exponential has a positive exponent and grow faster that $(1+t)^4$ the integral will diverge.

Sorry It's $p\leq 2.$

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

If $p=2$ the integral of $(1+t)^{-2}$ is convergent. If $p<2$ the integrated function is bounded by $e^{-at}$ where $a=1-p/2>0,$ hence it is convergent. For $p>2$ the integrated functions tends to $\infty$ for $t\to \infty,$ so the integral diverges.
